# How to send AddressZip along with card details to `Stripe` API for creating token in Android

Tags: android, stripe-payments

How we can send AddressZip along with cardNumber,cardExpMonth,cardExpYear,cardCVV to stripe Api for creating token in Android.

Here is my code:

```
Card card = new Card(cardNumber,Integer.valueOf(cardExpMonth),Integer.valueOf(cardExpYear),cardCVV);
if (haveNetworkConnection()) {
  new Stripe().createToken(card,key,new TokenCallback() {
    public void onSuccess(Token token) {
      Log.d("Stripe Token", " Successful!");
      Log.d("Stripe Token is ","" + token.getId());
      stripeToken = token.getId();
      jsonHandler.stripeDetailsToServer(String.valueOf(userId),stripeToken,String.valueOf(cardLastFourNumbers),LinkDebitCard.this);
    }
    public void onError(Exception error) {
      Log.d("Main Activity", "Connection Failed");
      Log.d("Main Activity", String.valueOf(error));
      StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(String.valueOf(error),":");
      String errorStrip = tokens.nextToken();
      String errorStripDisplay = tokens.nextToken();
      toast =  Toast.makeText(activity,errorStripDisplay,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
      Application.setToastDuration(toast);
      hideProgressDialog();
    }
  } );
}
else {
  toast = Toast.makeText(activity,Constants.TOAST_NO_INTERNET_CONNECTION,Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
  Application.setToastDuration(toast);
  hideProgressDialog();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How we can send AddressZip along with
>   cardNumber,cardExpMonth,cardExpYear,cardCVV to stripe Api for creating
>   token in Android

`addressZip` getter/setter method is also avalaible in Card class which we can use to pass address zip with card details like:

```
Card card = new Card(cardNumber,
            Integer.valueOf(cardExpMonth),
            Integer.valueOf(cardExpYear),cardCVV); 
// set zip here
card.setAddressZip("pass zip code value here");
```